# Post data along with photo to django rest with requests package

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, pyqt

I wrote an api with django rest and I want to post data and photo with requests package.
When I want to send data like this ->

```
data = {
         'name':'data',
         'price':'123',
         'category':1 }
```

everything works correctly and the data is saved in the database, but when I want to send a photo along with the data, I get this error->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\New folder (6)\PyQt5\app.py", line 58, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "F:\New folder (6)\PyQt5\app.py", line 48, in __init__
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data) , headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable
```

this is my django rest:

```
models.py
class Menu(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.IntegerField()
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)



serializers.py
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'name', 'price', 
                  'category','availability')


views.py
class MenuViewset(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Menu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
```

and this is my post request with the requests package that I wrote in PyQt:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/'
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                                  
                
    data = {'image':('chat2.png', open('chat2.png','rb'),"multipart/form-data"),
             'name':'data',
             'price':'123',
             'category':1 }

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)  , headers=headers)
   



if __name__ == '__main__':

  app = QApplication([])
  window = MainWindow()
  app.exec_()
```

Comment: `I get an error`: Care to share the error message?

Comment: @Selcuk Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

Comment: That's not very useful, but try `open('chat2.png','rb').read()`. Always post the whole error message with full traceback. Also edit your question to include the error, don't post them as comments.

Comment: @ُSelcuk Yes, but the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

1. you are blocking the eventloop on `requests.post` use `QNetworkAccessManager` or something (`open` is also blocking).
2. You haven't called `read()` on `open`
3. `open` is intended to use as a context-manager
   so if you want to use `open` do it like this:

```py
with open("chat2.png", "rb") as image_fh:
    data = {
        "image": ("chat2.png", image_fh.read(), "multipart/form-data"),
        "name": "data",
        "price": "123",
        "category": 1,
    }
```

Comment: I did not work with QNetworkAccessManager...
Can you teach me how to post data along with photo in this API using QNetworkAccessManager ?

Comment: @Mehdi first make sure that this was the error cause, later you can pose another question on how to use `QNetworkAccessManager` with this usecase.